# Why data points of the same category are not plotted on the same horizontal line by `seaborn.stripplot`?

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

In the script below, I want to use `seaborn.stripplot` to plot a `pandas` dataframe

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns 
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

classes = ["A","B","C","D","E"]
example = {ind:np.random.choice(classes,np.random.randint(1,len(classes)),replace=False) for ind in range(1,11)}

all_pairs = []
for key,val in example.items():
    for inner in val:
        all_pairs.append([key,inner])
df = pd.DataFrame(all_pairs,columns=['int','str'])
df = df.sort_values(by='str').reset_index(drop=True)

sns.stripplot(x='int',y='str',data=df)
```

the output figure is

[image: output]

as you can see, data points of the same category, for example `A`, are **not plotted on the same horizontal line**. From [`seaborn.stripplot`'s documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.stripplot.html), I learned that

> This function always treats one of the variables as categorical

I'm not sure if this causes the problem.

Is it possible to plot the data points on the same lines with `seaborn.stripplot`? I also tried `seaborn.catplot`, while it suffers from the same issue.

Comment: `sns.stripplot(x='int',y='str',data=df, jitter=False)` - `jitter=True` is the default.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually ni one-line which is horizonal for vertical you can change x and y axis.

```
sns.stripplot(x='str',y='int',data=df)
sns.catplot(x='str',y='int',data=df)
```

[image]